# Replace column values with last occurance value based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe has two columns, code and name,

each duplicated code may have different names,

How can I replace name for each code with last occurrence for each one

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 |

Required output

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by the column `code` and get the `last` value from the column `name` for each value of `code`. Use `transform` to get the complete column back and save it under the column `name`:

```
df['name'] = df.groupby('code').name.transform('last')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   code  name
0     1     7
1     1     7
2     2     5
3     3     4
4     1     7
```